# Is the verb use in this sentence correct?

Tags: tense, passive-voice, adverbial-phrases, reduced-relative-clauses

> When finished with digging out ancient objects, archaeologists must interpret what they have found.

As far as l know 'V+ing' must be used in this example because we use 'V3' with passive. Am I wrong?

Comment: where is there a V+ing?

Comment: No l am not saying  there is one ,l am just saying  finished must be finishing

Comment: When finishing my work, I go slowly. When finished, I turn off my computer. :)

Comment: The second example has not same subjects

Answer (score 3):

When finished with digging out ancient objects, archaeologists must interpret what they have found.

**There is no passive in that sentence.**

*When finished with digging out ancient objects* is an adverbial phrase introduced by when.

Passive would be:
The work was finished [by someone, subject=the work].

V3 (here: finished) is merely a past participle, not a passive. It would have the same meaning as: when they are finished with digging out ancient objects, they must etc.

**When finished**, he left the campus. [adverbial phrase; subject= he]

**When finishing** his work, he usually drank a cup of coffee. [adverbial phrase, subject=he]

The first means: When he finished.

The second means: when he was engaged in the activity of finishing; it is a noun gerund. These are not verbs with subjects. These are phrases that use verbs forms.